# Outlook add-on / plugin to put all attachments in a shared folder automatically?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, addons

Is there an add-on to outlook that will automatically remove attachments from all incoming messages and save them in a shared folder, embeding links to them in the original email?

Answer (score 1):

[ReliefJet Essentials for Outlook](http://www.reliefjet.com/Product/Features#Attachments) can do that and much more. You will be able to use "Replace Attachments with Links" utility right in your Outlook rules. It can also perform the reverse operation by replacing links with corresponding attachments. There is also a tool to update attachments' folder to a new location. I recommend this product because I'm one of its developers.

Comment: Please remember that you need to be disclosing your affiliation when promoting your own products.